# draggable jquery get start parent() element

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to drag and drop Items with juery.

Right now I do have a "storage" with multiple items.

On the other site I have x boxes. each box can contain only 1 item.

Right now, I use the droppable function to set another class on the box, that only 1 box can be added which is work in:

```
 $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
     accept: ".draggable",
     activeClass: "draghover",
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
         if($( this ).hasClass("droppable")) {
             $( this ).removeClass("droppable").addClass( "droppable-");
         }
     } });
```

Now, I need to revert the Class, when I move back the item to the storage or to another box.
I tried this with the draggable.start function, but I cannot get the correct parent()

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        snap: ".droppable",
        snapMode: "inner",
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            alert($( this ).parent().attr("Class"));

        }
    });
```

this will all the time return the start position before the first dragging. Not the latest position.

Storage is look like:

```
<td valign="top" class="warenlager" bgcolor="grey" width="200">
    <div class="draggable" class="bild ui-widget-content" id="s73-1">S</div>
    <div class="draggable" class="bild ui-widget-content" id="s74-1">S</div>
</td>
```

Box are look like:

```
<td><div class="droppable" id="element 2"></div></td>
```

Regards

Answer (score 3):

If you want to revert the class of the box after the the draggable element is removed from the droppable (which is what I think you asking) then use the out event handler, so now the code would look something like:

```
 $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
 accept: ".draggable",
 activeClass: "draghover",
 drop: function( event, ui ) {
     if($( this ).hasClass("droppable")) {
         $( this ).removeClass("droppable").addClass( "droppable-");
     }
 },
 out: function()
 {
     $(this).addClass("droppable").removeClass( "droppable-");
 }
 });
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (**by ES6**):

[**Online demo (jsfiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/f59q39y5/3/)

```
// Create a class for dragged element
// I will create a new instance form this class when drag
function draggedElement(elementId, parentId) {
  this.id = elementId,
  this.parentId = parentId
};

// Array of dragged elements
// This array use for store dragged elements and their parent's id
var draggedElementList = [];

$('.draggable').draggable({
  start: function(event, ui) {
    // Store or update parent's id  
    updateDraggedElementList($(this).attr("id"), $(this).parent().attr("id"));
  }
});

// This method used for update or store draaged elemens and their parent's id
function updateDraggedElementList(elementId, parentId) {

  // Create new instance
  var element = new draggedElement(elementId, parentId);

  // Check element has already been added or not
  var foundIndex = draggedElementList.findIndex(el => el.id == element.id);
  if (foundIndex > -1)
    draggedElementList[foundIndex] = element;
  else
    draggedElementList.push(element);

  // Print dragged elements and their parents
  printDraggedElements();
}

// I wrote this method for test
function printDraggedElements() {
  for (var i = 0; i < draggedElementList.length; i++) {
    console.log(draggedElementList[i].id);
    console.log(draggedElementList[i].parentId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't recent however one way of getting the parent element of the draggable item is to use the start event on draggable.

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    snap: ".droppable",
    snapMode: "inner",
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        alert(event.currentTarget.parentElement);
    }
});
```

Comment: console.log(event.currentTarget.parentElement); is null!